# How can I add PHPExcel_IOFactory in my custom module class in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, admin, frontend, php-extension

In this I need to add

```
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;
```

This two class in my module model file can any one guide me how can I add this two one in my model class I already added that but got error like

```
/var/www/html/pavilion/generated/code/WeltPixel
The directory '/var/www/html/pavilion/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #9 [ <required> PHPExcel_IOFactory $xlsx ] of Ccc\Brightpearl\Model\Jcproducts class

In ClassReader.php line 51:
                                                                                                                                             
  Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #9 [ <required> PHPExcel_IOFactory $xlsx ] of Ccc\Brightpearl\Model\Jcproducts class  
                                                                                                                                             

In ClassReader.php line 71:
                                           
  Class PHPExcel_IOFactory does not exist
```

My class file is as follow

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace  Ccc\Brightpearl\Model;
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory; 
use \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

/**
 * Brightpearl module observer
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 */
class Jcproducts
{
    const FTP_SERVER = '113.161.162.13';
    const FTP_SERVER2 = '118.69.32.112';
    const FTP_SERVER3 = '113.161.163.238';
    const FTP_USERNAME = 'jcuk';
    const FTP_PASSWORD = 'FR8VdKgJ';
    const FTP_DIR_PATH = 'JC-UK/DAILY INVENTORY';

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Ftp
     */
    protected $ftp;

    protected $directory;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Ccc\Brightpearl\Model\WarehouseFactory
     */
    protected $warehouseFactory;
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
    */
    protected $productFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Ccc\Brightpearl\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $brightpearlProductFactory;
    /**
     * @var ExcelFactory
     */
    protected $excelFactory;
    /**
     * @var FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    protected $xlsx;


    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Ftp $ftp,
       DirectoryList $dir,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
       \Ccc\Brightpearl\Model\ProductFactory $brightpearlProductFactory,
       \Ccc\Brightpearl\Model\WarehouseFactory $warehouseFactory,
       \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
       \Magento\Framework\Convert\ExcelFactory $excelFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
       \PHPExcel $xlsx
    ){
       $this->ftp = $ftp;
       
       $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
       $this->brightpearlProductFactory = $brightpearlProductFactory;
       $this->warehouseFactory = $warehouseFactory;
       $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
       $this->excelFactory = $excelFactory;
       $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
       $this->xlsx = $xlsx;
       $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
       $this->directoryList = $dir;
    }

    /**
     * Upload Inventory File On Server
     * @return void
     */
    public function uploadInventoryFile()
    {
        /*command jcproduct:generatefeed*/
        $file = $this->createInventoryFile();        
        $ftp_source_file_name = $this->directoryList->getPath('var').'/export/jc/'.$file;
        if(file_exists($ftp_source_file_name))
        {
            $ftp_dest_file_name = $file;
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/JcInventoryFileUpload.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);

            if($this->ftp_file(self::FTP_SERVER, self::FTP_USERNAME, self::FTP_PASSWORD, $ftp_source_file_name, self::FTP_DIR_PATH, $ftp_dest_file_name, $logger))
            {
                $logger->info("Success: FTP'd data");
            } 
            elseif ($this->ftp_file(self::FTP_SERVER2, self::FTP_USERNAME, self::FTP_PASSWORD, $ftp_source_file_name, self::FTP_DIR_PATH, $ftp_dest_file_name, $logger)) 
            {
                $logger->info("Success: FTP'd data");
            }
            elseif ($this->ftp_file(self::FTP_SERVER3, self::FTP_USERNAME, self::FTP_PASSWORD, $ftp_source_file_name, self::FTP_DIR_PATH, $ftp_dest_file_name, $logger)) 
            {
                $logger->info("Success: FTP'd data");
            }
        }

    }

    public function ftp_file($ftpservername, $ftpusername, $ftppassword, $ftpsourcefile, $ftpdirectory, $ftpdestinationfile, $logger)
    {
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpservername);
        if ( $conn_id == false )
        {
            $logger->info('FTP open connection failed to $ftpservername');
            return false;
        }
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpusername, $ftppassword);
        if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
            $logger->info('FTP connection has failed!');
            $logger->info("Attempted to connect to " . $ftpservername . " for user " . $ftpusername);
            return false;
        } else {
            $logger->info("Connected to " . $ftpservername . ", for user " . $ftpusername);
        }
        if ( strlen( $ftpdirectory ) > 0 )
        {
            if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $ftpdirectory )) {
                $logger->info("Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id));
            } else {
                $logger->info("Couldn't change directory on $ftpservername");
                return false;
            }
        }
        ftp_pasv ( $conn_id, true ) ;
        
        $upload = ftp_put( $conn_id, $ftpdestinationfile, $ftpsourcefile,  FTP_BINARY );
        if (!$upload) {
            $logger->info("$ftpservername: FTP upload has failed!");
            return false;
        } else {
            $logger->info("Uploaded " . $ftpsourcefile . " to " . $ftpservername . " as " . $ftpdestinationfile);
        }
        ftp_close($conn_id);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _getBrandOptions()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $eavConfig = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Eav\Model\Config");

        $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');

        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

        $key = array_search("Jonathan Charles",array_column($options,'label'));        

        return $options[$key]['value'];
    }

    protected function _getColumnHeader()
    {
        $headers = ['Territory','JCITEM','JCDESC','JCOH','JCTRN','JCVORD','JCNYOR','JCHIS6','JCHIST','JCHI24','JCHI36','JCLINV'];
        return $headers;
    }

    public function createInventoryFile()
    {
        $brandId = $this->_getBrandOptions();       
     

        $filepath = 'export/jc/JcProducts.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $columns = $this->_getColumnHeader();
        $header = [];
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $header[] = $column;
        }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

         $ashchurchWarehouseId = $this->warehouseFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("warehouse_name",array("eq"=>"Ashchurch Warehouse"))->getFirstItem()->getWarehouseId();
        $goodsInTransitId = $this->warehouseFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("warehouse_name",array("eq"=>"Goods In Transit"))->getFirstItem()->getWarehouseId();
        $productCollection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => $brandId)); // Id 30 "Jonathan Charles"

        foreach ($productCollection as $key => $_product) 
        {
            $brightpearlProduct = $this->brightpearlProductFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter("product_id",array("eq"=>$_product->getId()))
                ->addFieldToFilter("warehouse_id",array($ashchurchWarehouseId,$goodsInTransitId));
                
            $itemData = [];
            $ashQty = 0;
            $gdntQty = 0;
            if($brightpearlProduct->getSize()){
                foreach($brightpearlProduct as $_productData){
                    if($_productData->getWarehouseId() == $ashchurchWarehouseId){
                        $ashQty = (int) $_productData->getWarhOnHandQty();
                    }
                    if($_productData->getWarehouseId() == $goodsInTransitId){
                        $gdntQty = (int) $_productData->getWarhOnHandQty();
                    }

                }
                $itemData[] = 'UK';                
                $itemData[] = $_product->getSku();
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = $ashQty;
                $itemData[] = $gdntQty;
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = '0';
                $itemData[] = '0';           
                $stream->writeCsv($itemData);     
            }
        }        
 
        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        //$content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder
 
        $csvfilename = 'JcProducts.csv';
        $this->fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,'application/octet-stream');

        return $csvfilename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the package with composer first? Also that library seems to be discontinued (https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel) and replaced by https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet which is the one I use

Once the package is installed via composer, you can include the clases like:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```